# MongoDB 5.0 timeseries collections, the metaField, and "other" fields

Tags: mongodb, time-series

The timeseries collection is created with 1 required parameter `timeField` to identify which field in the inbound docs contains the BSON datetime value that will be used for the series bucketing.  The `metaField` is optional and the MongoDB docs describe it thusly:

```
The name of the field which contains metadata in each time series document.
The metadata in the specified field should be data that is used to label a
unique series of documents.
The metadata should rarely, if ever, change.
```

That is fine but exactly what special behaviors/capabilities are enabled by declaring a `metaField`?   Querying is of course supported but in my experiments there seems to be no difference between placing data in the `metaField` "wrapper" vs. just having additional discrete fields, e.g.:

```
tscoll.insert({timestamp: dtval, meta: {area: "X", flavor: "Z"}, val: 444});
tscoll.find({"meta.flavor":"Z"});
or
tscoll.insert({timestamp: dtval, area: "X", flavor: "Z", val: 444});
tscoll.find({"flavor":"Z"});
```

Is this a convention-oriented design guideline to clearly separate the timestamp, values collected (can be more than one), and 1 or more pieces of additional data?

Comment: There is a bit more information at https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/new-time-series-collections/#metafield

Comment: As far as I know, you can only create indexes on defined timeField and metaField.  For metaField these could be secondary indexes.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries-collections/#index

Comment: From the link provided by Joe above, the metaField is used in internal storage optimizations:  `Measurements with a common metaField for periods of time will be grouped together internally to eliminate the duplication of this field at the storage layer. `

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned earlier in the comments:

> *"The metaField, if present, should partition the time-series data, so that measurements with the same metadata relate over time. Measurements with a common metaField for periods of time will be grouped together internally to eliminate the duplication of this field at the storage layer." — [Source](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/new-time-series-collections/#metafield)*

John Page, explains and visualizes this storage optimization in his [introduction video](https://youtu.be/xu2AkGVI37E?t=141), and compares it to a database that is not optimized for time series. tldr is:

[image: Mongodb 5 time series metafield storage optimization]